# How does pipelined connection over persistent connection work?

Tags: http, tcp

I read about **the persistent connection over persistent connection** from the < The HTTP Definite Guide > by David Courley.

The book's illustration is like this:

[image]

But I think it should be like this:

[image]

As the book said, the pipeline approach can improve performance in a high-latency environment. So I think **the whole point of pipeline here is to fully utilize the latency time to initiate as many requests as possible.**

But if the first illustration is correct, how can we explain the overlapping of request 3 and response 1 over the same TCP connection?  And similarly, the overlapping of request 4 and response 2.

So the question reside in:

Can a computer send and receive data over a single TCP connection at the same time?

Comment: The last sentence is the crux of what you're asking, so you should consider making that the title (and, in fact, dropping everything else!)

Comment: I add the illustration to avoid misunderstanding. And give some context about the question.